# A medical tool riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Doctors used me to perfume perspiration,
My start invokes electric dissuasion,
My middle is a place in Canada,
But my end, in territories is imperative.

Extra lines:

> I have six letters, but my plural has three more,
>  You’d say them with a child to your Labrador.

Extra Extra lines:

> My origin came from ancient Greek,
>  But it's no longer a word that people speak.

Extra Extra Extra lines:

> Though I am not used any more,
>  My principle remains, in another form,

What am I?

Comment: If no one gets this I will start a bounty on it when I can

Comment: I am a little confused. In your First line you say that doctors use it, then in your last hint you say it is not used any more. These seem to contradict each other

Comment: @Cubemaster One means the word and another means the actual thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First line:

> The answer is empasm.It is a powder used to mask the smell of sweat and it was used and prescribed by doctors to people who wanted it, and doctors used it on people who they were operating on.

Second line:

> EMP Electro Magnetic Pulse, disables electric stuff within a radius

Third line:

> The PAS a place in canada

Final line:

> ASM air space management (who owns which parts of the sky)

Extra line:

> Empasm = 6
> Empasmata = 9
> Ata + boy (small child)

Extra Extra line:

> Empasma = to sprinkle on
> No one uses that word amymore

Extra Extra Extra line:

> No one uses it
> It’s literally deodorant, people use deodorant

Comment: I've upvoted this, of course, but could you add some more explanation for each part? I still don't really understand how EMP, PAS, ASM fit with the riddle as stated.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Does this help?

Comment: Technically, the plural of [your word] is [your word]s. The word [your word]ata is the plural of a derivative word from yours, [your word]a instead.

Comment: Hmm, sorry, when I looked it up I got empasmata as a plural, but now I'm seeing empasms...

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer**

Judging from the first line and the second hint, this is likely to be

> a medical term, probably one not found in a lot of dictionaries.

So let's try to piece it together from the wordplay.

*My start invokes electric dissuasion,*

> This makes me think of electro-shock therapy or electro-convulsive therapy. Perhaps the start of the word is EST or ECT? (We know it's a six-letter word thanks to the first hint.)

*My middle is a place in Canada,*

> I'd guess, given the length of the word, that this is going to be an abbreviation for some well-known Canadian city. Perhaps TOR for Toronto?

*But my end, in territories is imperative.*

> Still haven't figured this out. I suspect there might be wordplay involved, e.g. "imperative" meaning the imperative form of a verb rather than just necessary.

Overall, it looks like we have

> a 6-letter medical term beginning with EST or ECT, possibly ESTOR or ECTOR. I've checked some online resources, and the only matching medical terms I could find were ECTOMY and ECTOPY and ESTHES, none of which really fits the bill.

Comment: Rand, I was thinking about this one a lot with no success. Maybe you have some better ideas. A good place to focus on might be the first hint - I don't know many (any, really) 6 letter words whose plural is 9 letters long....

Comment: The only word I can think of that gets three letters longer is child/children but I don't know of any other words that follow that form. For the Canadian place, I was thinking it would be a postal abbreviation. For example, NL for Newfoundland and Labrador (note possible reference in hint 1).

Comment: The only Ancient Greek tool that I thought of that relates to sweat is _strigil_, but it fits next to none of the clues. I guess it has 6 distinct letters, and a possible archaic plural is strigiles? But I think this is far off.

Comment: Comedo(nes) hits some spots but not greek or Canada. Come do(g) :)

Comment: Med as in Medicine Hat, Alberta, perhaps? Or perhaps ME as in Maine, our unofficial 12th province?

Comment: Good guess, but the place in canada is the actual name of the place. Well, close enough to it. You are closer to it than the other answer, when the bounty gets to a few hours I'll give it to you and give you the answer. Hint: the first part of your word is very close!

Comment: Perhaps the place is Emo, Ontario? Short enough to fit in a 6-letter word :)

Comment: Perhaps something like Herbal? or Herbalism? HE is a low reactivity element and it matches the 6/9 length

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally gave my bounty to the wrong person. I will give you 100 in 24 hours for you trouble though